# How can I print two lists in one column in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I face this issue if I want to print two lists in a column in Flutter. As you know, we can print a list in column like below:

```
Column(
  children:List.generate(list1.length, (index)=>
    // some widgets here
  ),
)
```

But how can I generate it from two lists like below:

```
Column(
  children:<Widget> [
    // some widgets here,
    List.generate(list1.length, (index)=>
      // some widgets here
    ),
    List.generate(list2.length, (index)=>
      // some widgets here
    ),
  // some widgets here,
  ]
)
```

Comment: Do you want the lists to be separate, or can they be part of the same ListView. You should be using a ListView, by the way, instead of a Column, for variable sized Lists that may need more screen space and require scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) for that:

```
 Column(
   children: [
     some widgets here,
     ...List.generate(list1.length, (index)=>
       // some widgets here
     ),
     ...List.generate(list2.length, (index)=>
       // some widgets here
     ),
     // some widgets here,
   ]
 )
```

Prior to 2.3.0 when the collections operators were introduced, you'd have to do this manually:

```
Column(
  children: [/* First widgets */]
    ..addAll(List.generate(...))
    ..addAll(List.generate(...)),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but spread operator  is accessible from version 2.3.0. Do we have any other method for earlier version?

Comment: Added a pre-2.3.0 version. However, the comment above is right, you may want to consider ListViews.

Comment: I have multiply widgets that all of them should be scrolled and I put all of them in CustomScrollView. Thank you , you teached something new to me